# python test if number is next to a number in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to find the most next number to one number in a list?

```
numbers = [1000, 999, 600, 476, 380, 280]
number = 300

def get_most_next_number(numbers_list, number):
    # CODE HERE

get_most_next_number(numbers, number)
>>> 380
```

Comment: What if there is no next number?

Comment: I think you need to explain what you mean by "most next" ... *precisely*.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is next most number, one approach is based on using the `key` parameter of [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)

```
numbers = [1000, 999, 600, 476, 380, 280]
number = 300

def get_most_next_number(numbers_list, number):
    return max(numbers, key=lambda x: (x > number, number - x))

print(get_most_next_number(numbers, number))
```

**Output**

```
380
```

To better understand what is happening in the above code let's look at the following:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: (x > 280, 280 - x), [999, 380, 280]))
[(True, -719), (True, -100), (False, 0)]
```

As it can be seen those value above 280 are map to True (or 1) and those below are map to False (or 0), any existing value above 280 will be greater than any below. The second coordinate of the tuple breaks the ties between those above, the closer to 280 the greater the second coordinate is.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this (A more explainable approach):

```
def get_most_next_number(number_list, number):
  temp = ####A very large number such as np.inf
  idx = None
  for i in number_list:
    if(i-number>=0 and i-number<temp):
      temp = i-number
      idx = i
  return idx
```